# how i can implement a get method to a api what needs "Temporary Headers"?

Tags: javascript, methods, get, postman, token

I made an api using Net.Core 'https://localhost:44351/api/usuarios' with Authorize attribute for use a validation token for access to this api. This token is generated by another api and works well. 
When i use Postman for acess to api 'https://localhost:44351/api/usuarios' i need put in the Authorization tab the token previously generated (see https://i.ibb.co/Lg7rD4N/2.png) and this way i get access for the api (see https://i.ibb.co/0BqnPhR/3.png)

But the huge problem is when i try from a JAVASCRIPT CLIENT use method GET using FETCH. I know need to do a object like this for make correct request

```
let params= {   method: 'GET',
                headers: {"X-Auth-Token": "5f5fe128570248a9bd198add1a5b25e4"}
            };
```

So my question is how i can implement the attributte  'Temporary-Headers' in the object 'params' like Postman does ( https://i.ibb.co/0BqnPhR/3.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Temporary Headers" are just like any other Header, those are just values auto-generated by the web client. I believe your problem relies on how you send your Header if you are using the fetch API modify your parameters like the following.

```
{
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <replace with your token>"
  }
}
```

This is how postman is sending the request as seen in the screenshots you provide.